# How to delay multiple messages in parallel?

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

I am doing some TCP programming and I want to simulate some latency.

Each "message" (a byte[] representing a serialized object) must be delayed by some time `t`. I thought that I can have one function to collect raw messages:

```
private Queue<byte[]> rawMessages = new Queue<byte[]>();
private void OnDataReceived(object sender, byte[] data)
{
    rawMessages.Enqueue(data);
}
```

Another method with a while-loop to continuously read from `rawMessages` and then delay each one:

```
private Queue<byte[]> delayedRawMessages = new Queue<byte[]>();
delayMessagesInTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    while (true) //TODO: Swap a cancellation token
    {
        if(rawMessages.Count > 0){
            var rawMessage = rawMessages.Dequeue();
            //???
            //Once the message has been delayed, enqueue it into another buffer.
            delayedRawMessages.Enqueue(rawMessage);
        }
    }
});
```

I thought that to delay each message, I could have another method to spawn a thread which uses `Thread.Sleep(t)` to wait for time `t` and then enqueue `delayedRawMessages`. I'm sure this will work, but I think there must be a better way. The issue with the `Thread.Sleep` approach is that message 2 might finish being delayed before message 1... I obviously need the messages to be delayed **and done so in the correct order**, otherwise I would not be using TCP.

I'm looking for a way to do this that will delay for as close to time `t` as possible and will not impact the rest of the application by slowing it down.

Does anyone here know of a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to go the producer/multiple consumer approach.

```
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class LatencySimulator {

    public enum SimulatorType { UP, DOWN };

    public SimulatorType type;
    public int latency = 0;
    public int maxConsumers = 50;
    public BlockingCollection<byte[]> inputQueue = new BlockingCollection<byte[]>(new ConcurrentQueue<byte[]>());
    public Queue<byte[]> delayedMessagesQueue = new Queue<byte[]>();

    void CreateConsumers()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < maxConsumers; i++)
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Consumer(),TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
        }
    }

    private void Consumer()
    {
        foreach (var item in inputQueue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
        {
            Thread.Sleep(latency);  
            delayedMessagesQueue.Enqueue(item);
        }
    }
}
```

To use it, create a new `LatencySimulator`, set its 'type', max consumers and latency to simulate. Call `CreateConsmers()` and then populate the `inputQueue`. When the messages have been delayed, they will appear in the `delayedMessagesQueue`.

I do not really know if this is an ideal way to achieve my goal, but it works... for now.